# Multiple spring mvc controllers needing same data

Tags: spring-mvc, fullcalendar

I am integrating fullcalendar with spring mvc.

Every spring mvc example I have found online talks just about CRUD on a particular object, and doesn't cover how to deal with multiple views that may need the same data.

I have a Person bean and a PersonEvent bean. The person bean will have its own CRUD views with a standard @controller. For PersonEvent, I want a view that gives a list of persons and the ability to CRUD an event for a selected person, and I need it to be restful so I presume I should use @restcontroller for the controller. But both requirements need a call to get a list of persons.

Should I write two distinct getpersons, one in personcontroller and one in personeventcontroller? It seems redundant given the input and output is exactly the same? Should I merge them into the same controller, with the caveat that if I have other requirements (PersonPayment, PersonAddress) that this controller could get enormous?

I appreciate here I'm probably not fully grasping how to implement the MVC pattern so I'm just after some advice on best practice and real world implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't duplicate code.  DRY must be preserved.

A better solution would be to write a service that both controllers could call to get `Person` data and return it in the model.

Comment: Ok I've done a bit of reading and I see the value in DAO and service layers. Would I just have one service layer or multiple?

Comment: One layer, multiple services in it.

Comment: So I would create personService and personEventService and on include them both in personEventController?

Comment: I don't know; it's your problem.  If you want person data, yes it sounds like a PersonService or PersonDao might be a good idea.  I don't know what events you have in mind.  I won't design a system in comments.

Comment: I think it's largely a matter of preference Stevie. There is not a "correct" way to divvy up your services. I tend to keep a single Service class managing one type of entity and optionally very closely related entities but as duffy says, it's your decision.